# Facebook Open Graph still has the old meta data while debugger shows the latest

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I added the following code in functions.php (wordpress) to add metadata dynamically as it differs on every page.

```
//facebook opengraph

//Adding the Open Graph in the Language Attributes
function add_opengraph_doctype( $output ) {
        return $output . ' xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"';
    }
add_filter('language_attributes', 'add_opengraph_doctype');

//Lets add Open Graph Meta Info

function insert_fb_in_head() {
    global $post;
    if ( !is_singular()) //if it is not a post or a page
        return;
        echo '<meta property="fb:app_id" content="???"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:title" content="' . get_the_title() . '"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:url" content="' . get_permalink() . '?fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:site_name" content="MY SITE"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:image:width" content="100"/>';
        echo '<meta property="og:image:height" content="100"/>';
    if(!has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) { //the post does not have featured image, use a default image
        $default_image="www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Marine-1.jpg"; //replace this with a default image on your server or an image in your media library
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . $default_image . '"/>';
    }
    else{
        $thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'medium' );
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail_src[0] ) . '"/>';
    }
    echo "
";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'insert_fb_in_head', 5 );
```

Previously I added the Open Graph meta data in header directly which was not dynamic for testing purposes.

Now as I scrap for new metadata in debugger, it shows the correct one. But when I click the share button on my site, it still shows the old meta data which doesn't exist any more.

Even the page source shows the correct /latest meta data, but the sharer still shows the old, non-existing meta data.

How do I make sure, new meta data is fetched on every page that I click share button?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a caching issue? Ask someone to try to share your URL on FB... no need to post, just pasting your blog link and see what Open Graph info comes on the preview.

Comment: @brasofilo, when pasting the link on fb, I see the updated metadata. Even the debugger also shows the same, but only the sharer dialog box keep showing the very old meta data which I've already deleted from header. This part is cached somewhere and seems to be difficult to detect. Because even the share button is cached it seems. I remove the share button but the page still shows it.

Comment: I think it'd be important to check it from another FB account and another computer.

Comment: @brasofilo, checked in another computer with another account

Answer (score 0):

You have to send cache clear request to FB api. But it tooks 
For eg. via curl (but it tooks long time)

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'id='.$url.'&scrape=true'); //site url
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: multipart/form-data'));

$curl_results = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Maybe try via javascript